# Is it possible to extract all subtitles tracks using one command?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitles

Is it possible to extract all subtitles tracks (at the same time) using one command?

We can use `ffmpeg -i <video file> -map 0:s:<index> subs.srt` but if we have video container file with many subtitles we have to execute this command many times (and do `index++` after each command)

Comment: Do you know the number of subs?

Comment: @Gyan yes, seems I found solution https://brontosaurusrex.github.io/2017/01/17/ffmpeg-extract-multiple-audio-tracks/ as I understand it will be much faster (time executing) than execute command for each subtitles separately. is it correct that it is much faster?

Comment: @Gyan also is there any difference between `-map 0:s:0 -c copy` and just `-map 0:s:0` (without copy) when using it for subrip (srt) track? will ffmpeg understand that it should not convert anything if it's already has needed format?

Comment: No, you need to keep the `-c copy` for each output.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users:

Example: Extract all subtitles from chapter 0 to 31 (step by 1) from video S01E01.mkv to files S01E01_0.sub S01E01_1.sub ... S01E01_31.sub

```
FOR /L %X IN (0,1,31) DO ffmpeg -i S01E01.mkv -map 0:s:%X -c copy S01E01_%X.sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Example: Extract all subtitles from  0 to 4 step by 1

```
    for /L %%X in (0,1,4) do (
    
    for %%A in ("*.mp4" "*.avi" "*.mkv") do (
    
    %ffmpeg% -i "%%A" -vn -map 0:s:%%X -c copy subs_%%X.srt
    
    )

)
```